# Unpivoting in db2

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, unpivot

I have the below table

```
+------+------+---+---+---+
| type | year | a | b | c |
+------+------+---+---+---+
| x    | 2015 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| x    | 2015 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| x    | 2017 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| y    | 2016 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| y    | 2017 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| z    | 2015 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| z    | 2016 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
+------+------+---+---+---+
```

The expected result must be as follows

```
+------+------+---+---+---+
| type | year | x | y | z |
+------+------+---+---+---+
| a    | 2015 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| a    | 2016 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| a    | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| b    | 2015 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| b    | 2016 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| b    | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| c    | 2015 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| c    | 2016 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| c    | 2017 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
+------+------+---+---+---+
```

So far, I could write the following query to obtain the result using simple group by in a pivot table manner, but i need to display the result in the unpivot manner as my expected result shown as above.

```
select type, year, sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c from table group by type,year;
```

The result of the above query is a valuable result for me but in a different format

```
+------+------+---+---+---+
| type | year | a | b | c |
+------+------+---+---+---+
| x    | 2015 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| x    | 2017 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| y    | 2016 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| y    | 2017 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| z    | 2015 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| z    | 2016 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
+------+------+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot using `union all` and then reaggregate:

```
select col_type, year,
       sum(case when type = 'x' then val end) as x,
       sum(case when type = 'y' then val end) as y,
       sum(case when type = 'z' then val end) as z
from (select type, year, 'a' as col_type, a as val from t union all
      select type, year, 'b' as col_type, b as val from t union all
      select type, year, 'c' as col_type, c as val from t 
     ) x
group by col_type, year;
```

Comment: Is there any other way i could rewrite this query when i have 100 a,b,c,.... as columns in my table using any of the window functions

Comment: @saikumarvoruganti . . . Window functions won't help in the sense that you still need to list all the columns.  You can use a spreadsheet or query to help write the code.